# Micrometer timer exception handling

Tags: apache-kafka, micrometer

I want to handle exception thrown in method which is recorded. For example, I send message to kafka with method `kafka.send()`, I record it: `timer.record(() -> kafka.send())`
Kafka may produce some exception and if its happened, I want to make some kind of transaction and rollback some code. How can I handle exception thrown in kafka.send method? As I saw in code of timer.record, it swallows exception, is it right?

Comment: The send call only tracks the time the record is added to the internal producer buffer, not to the broker. For that, you'd want to time the flush method. What exception are you referring to here?

Comment: For example when kafka is stopped, so we can't push message, so we have an exception

Comment: That exception will happen during flush. Like I said, send only appends records to an in-memory buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `timer.record` method doesn't swallow the exception. There is only finally-block, but no catch-block: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/AbstractTimer.java

And you can handle the exception in your code as usual.